# Small automated script

Tags: python, scripting

I need your help for a small script, because my python skills are very low.

I would like to automate on my selected objects:

- Duplicate object "linked"
- Constrain duplicate to original object with "Transforms"
- Set all material_slots of duplicate to "object"
- Override all empty materials with custom material. A black one for example
- Move duplicate with black materials to specific layer

It would be nice if this would work on a hierarchy so it would be possible to do this with rigs.

This is what I have done so far, the biggest problem is to set a material to the empty slots.

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    ob.select = True

    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":True, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0,   0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED',       "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0),     "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False})

    ob.select = True

    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

    bpy.ops.object.constraint_add_with_targets(type='COPY_TRANSFORMS')

    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("#BLACK")

    new = bpy.context.selected_objects[1]

    for matslot in new.material_slots:
        i = ob.material_slots.find(matslot.name)

        matslot.link = 'OBJECT'
```

Answer (score 1):

The result without calling operators.

```
import bpy

from bpy import context
# all mesh objects
meshobs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
# black material (or None)
black = bpy.data.materials.get('BLACK')
# copy layer
copy_layer = 19
copy_layers = [i == copy_layer for i in range(20)] 
if black is None:
    print("WARNING: no black material")

scene = context.scene

for o in meshobs:
    # linked copy
    copy = o.copy()
    # new copy transforms constraint
    ct = copy.constraints.new('COPY_TRANSFORMS')
    # set target to original
    ct.target = o
    # loop thru material slots
    for slot in copy.material_slots:
        # object link
        slot.link = 'OBJECT'
        # set to black material
        if slot.material is None:
            slot.material = black

    # link to scene
    scene.objects.link(copy)
    # move to copy_layer (after linking to scene)
    copy.layers = copy_layers
```

It only sets existing slots with empty (`slot.material is None`) material to black.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it, works well so far. 
Now i have two buttons, one with black material and one without material.

The goal was to have a second viewport as an alpha mask to key the orignial viewport in realtime over a hardware picture mixer. I think there is a much more elegant way to do this, but im a beginner 
Biggest problem was to select and deselect the objects in the script.

Cheers Daniel

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Alpha",
    "author": "DanielPaul",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Tool Shelf > My Tab",
    "description": "Makes_object_to_alpha",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Duplicate",
    }

import bpy


def main(context):
    #get selected objects
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:

        #deselect all
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        #select only ob
        ob.select = True

        #dublicate linked    
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":True, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0,   0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED',       "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0),     "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False})

        #select new linked dublicate    
        ob.select = True
        #set original as active
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        #constraint "transform"
        bpy.ops.object.constraint_add_with_targets(type='COPY_TRANSFORMS')

        #select linked dublicate
        new = bpy.context.selected_objects[1]

        #change "data" in material slot to "object"    
        for matslot in new.material_slots:

            matslot.link = 'OBJECT'

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        new.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.move_to_layer(layers=(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True))

def second(context):
    #get selected objects
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:

        #get black mat
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get("#BLACK")

        if mat is None:
            # create material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="#BLACK")
            mat.diffuse_color = (0,0,0)
            mat.specular_color = (0,0,0)


        #deselect all
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        #select only ob
        ob.select = True

        #dublicate linked    
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":True, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0,   0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED',       "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0),     "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False})

        #select new linked dublicate    
        ob.select = True
        #set original as active
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        #constraint "transform"
        bpy.ops.object.constraint_add_with_targets(type='COPY_TRANSFORMS')

        #select linked dublicate
        new = bpy.context.selected_objects[1]

        #change "data" in material slot to "object"    
        for matslot in new.material_slots:

            matslot.link = 'OBJECT'


                #set black mat to empty mat slots in dublicate
        for i in range(len(new.material_slots)):
            new.material_slots[i].material = mat

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        new.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.move_to_layer(layers=(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True))

class WhiteAlphaDublicate(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "myops.white_alphadublicate"
    bl_label = "White alpha"


    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BlackAlphaDublicate(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "myops.black_alphadublicate"
    bl_label = "Black alpha"


    def execute(self, context):
        second(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class AlphaDublicatePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Tool Shelf"""
    bl_label = "Alpha dublicate"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_alpha"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Studio_tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("myops.white_alphadublicate")
        row.operator("myops.black_alphadublicate")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WhiteAlphaDublicate)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlackAlphaDublicate)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AlphaDublicatePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WhiteAlphaDublicate)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlackAlphaDublicate)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AlphaDublicatePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```